# NullPointerException when using layout

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I can run my app on a emulator without a problem, but when I try to play it on a phone I get this error

> "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference".

As far as I know I should be able to access `movieListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.movieListView);`with a incluce on my activity_main, like this one that I have:

> ```
> <include android:id="@+id/content"
>     layout="@layout/content_main" />
> ```

So I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

MainActivity.java

```
package br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    private MovieArrayAdapter movieArrayAdapter;
    private ListView movieListView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        movieListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.movieListView);
        movieArrayAdapter = new MovieArrayAdapter(this, movieList);
        movieListView.setAdapter(movieArrayAdapter);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TextInputEditText search_bar;
                search_bar = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
                URL url = createURL(search_bar.getText().toString());
                if(url != null){
                    dismissKeyboard(search_bar);
                    GetMovieTask getLocalMovieTask = new GetMovieTask();
                    getLocalMovieTask.execute(url);
                }else {
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout), R.string.invalid_url,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
        movieListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    default:
                        Movie review = movieArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
                        Intent nextActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShortReview.class);
                        nextActivity.putExtra("summary", review.getsummary());
                        startActivity(nextActivity);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void dismissKeyboard (View view){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);
    }

    private URL createURL (String movie){
        String apiKey = getString (R.string.api_key);
        String baseUrl = getString(R.string.nyt_url);
        try{
            String urlString = baseUrl + "?api_key=" + apiKey + "&query=" + URLEncoder.encode (movie, "UTF-8");
            return new URL(urlString);
        }
        catch( Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private class GetMovieTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, JSONObject> {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) params[0].openConnection();
                int response = connection.getResponseCode();
                if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder ();
                    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))){
                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                            builder.append(line);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e){
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout), R.string.read_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return new JSONObject(builder.toString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout), R.string.connect_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                if (connection != null){
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject movie) {
            convertJSONToArrayList (movie);
            movieArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            movieListView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
        }
    }

    private void convertJSONToArrayList (JSONObject forecast){
        movieList.clear();
        try{
            JSONArray results = forecast.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject movie = results.getJSONObject(i);
                if(movie.isNull("multimedia")){
                    movieList.add(new Movie(movie.getString("display_title"),
                            movie.getString("publication_date"),
                            "image", movie.getString("summary_short")));
                }else {
                    JSONObject multimedia = movie.getJSONObject("multimedia");
                    movieList.add(new Movie(movie.getString("display_title"),
                            movie.getString("publication_date"),
                            multimedia.getString("src"), movie.getString("summary_short")));
                }
            }
            if(results.length() == 0){
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout), R.string.no_movie,
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



}
```

Movie.java

```
package br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas;


public class Movie {
    public final String title;
    public final String publication_date;
    public final String iconURL;
    public final String short_summary ;

    public Movie(String title,String publication_date, String iconName, String short_summary) {
        this.title = title;
        this.publication_date = publication_date;
        this.iconURL = iconName;
        this.short_summary = short_summary;
    }

    public String getsummary() {
        return short_summary;
    }

}
```

MovieArrayAdapter.java

```
package br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MovieArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {

    private static class ViewHolder{
        ImageView movieImage;
        TextView description;
        TextView publication_date;
    }

    private Map<String, Bitmap> bitmaps = new HashMap<>();
    public MovieArrayAdapter (Context context, List<Movie>
            forecast){
        super (context, -1, forecast);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Movie review = getItem (position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.complete_review, parent, false);
            viewHolder.movieImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.movieImage);
            viewHolder.description = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            viewHolder.publication_date = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.publication_date);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        if(review.iconURL == "image"){
            viewHolder.movieImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_import_contacts_white_24dp);
        }
        else{
            new LoadImageTask (viewHolder.movieImage).execute (review.iconURL);
        }
        viewHolder.description.setText(review.title);
        viewHolder.publication_date.setText(review.publication_date);

        return convertView;
    }



    private class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private ImageView imageView;
        public LoadImageTask (ImageView imageView){
            this.imageView = imageView;
        }
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try{
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                try(InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream ()){
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    bitmaps.put (params[0], bitmap);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:elevation="@dimen/toolbar_elevation" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fab_magin_top"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:elevation="@dimen/rested_button_elevation"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />

    <include android:id="@+id/content"
        layout="@layout/content_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/view">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/search_bar"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="@string/hint_text"
            android:elevation="@dimen/rested_search_elevation"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/movieListView"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Error Message

```
07-28 21:18:00.812 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas E/Zygote: no v2
07-28 21:18:00.822 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-J110M_5.1.1 ver=48
07-28 21:18:00.822 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [1] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-J110M_5.1.1_0048
07-28 21:18:00.822 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
07-28 21:18:00.822 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
07-28 21:18:00.842 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas I/SAMP: ActivityThread() - SAMP_ENABLE : true
07-28 21:18:00.862 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: null for user  0
07-28 21:18:01.012 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: null for user  0
07-28 21:18:01.022 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas D/DisplayManager: DisplayManager()
07-28 21:18:01.022 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: null for user  0
07-28 21:18:01.092 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-28 21:18:01.172 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
07-28 21:18:01.172 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
07-28 21:18:01.362 5123-5138/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3506(700KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 27% free, 5MB/7MB, paused 7.831ms total 22.235ms
07-28 21:18:01.372 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
07-28 21:18:01.412 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-28 21:18:01.412 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas, PID: 5123
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2697)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1432)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2650)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1432) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200) 
07-28 21:29:10.422 8489-8489/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-28 21:29:10.522 8489-8489/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
07-28 21:29:10.522 8489-8489/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
07-28 21:29:10.612 8489-8489/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
07-28 21:29:10.612 8489-8489/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-28 21:29:10.612 8489-8489/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas, PID: 8489
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2697)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1432)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2650)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1432) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: You should make your question a [mcve] to hightlight the exact problem

Comment: I think the problem is because you are inflating `activity_main` in your main activity but the name of your main layout is `Content_main.xml`, use setContentView(R.layout.Content_main.xml) instead

Comment: I already tried that and I gives the same error =/
Sorry cricket_007 I thought this title was good, hope this one is better ^^

Comment: your layout is activity_main.xml right not Activity_main.xml if it compiles to your emulator then i'm sure you have it correct.  Have you tried to clean the project and redeploy to the phone?

Comment: tried cleaning and redeploying and still not working

Comment: Aparrently my app is bugging because of the screen Orientation, It works fine on my emulator on landscape but bugs out if changed to portrait... any way to solve this problem?

Comment: After this line: movieListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.movieListView);         Add System.out.println(movieListView); and tell me what you get. And try it in both orientations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I'm really dumb, since my project was for android 4.0 + and I was using elvation on my layout (which is only supported for 5.0 +), android studio made 2 different layouts, one for 5.0 - and one for 5.0 + and for some reason the layour for 5.0+ did not have the ListView on it.
I just added the ListView on v21/content_main and it worked!

Thx for everyone's help and sorry for the dumb mistake with poor explanation